# Are analog CRT oscilloscope becoming rare?

Tags: oscilloscope, crt

Back in the early 2000s I bought cheap Commodore 64 sets from eBay, we were able to get huge collections for under 100 USD. Today they are rare and commensurately expensive! Today you can get analog oscilloscopes off eBay for under 100 bucks or so, but I see in the shop windows and on the market tons of digital scopes and no analog ones. They are becoming rare, aren't they? You as professionals, would you say you'd no longer buy analog scopes for a professional bench? Or rather, you can see that most semi-pros would forego the purchase, and therefore the market of used analog scope will dry up in the near future?

Comment: I can't see any reason to buy a CRT scope any more. I don't know of any modern ones that are available form mainstream vendors.

Comment: Analog scopes may give an *appearance* of quiet which digital ones lack, but it's not always clear to what degree they're just hiding detail; there may be a few remaining real uses, but they may also at times be the "warm tube sound" praised for their *limitation* rather than *fidelity*.  If you feel you have a reason to collect them, great.  For many they aren't worth the bench space compared to their more compact and versatile digital replacements, and the question is if they're still worth the storage volume.  Many have also aged to the point of having issues, like dirty selector switches.

Comment: Perhaps the biggest thing for me is the highly interactive display in analog scopes. The vector display shows changes in real time. Adjustments are simple as there's no delay between a change and the observation of the effect on the waveform. Complex waveforms, like some TV video signals and AM RF are also displayed as expected. But I use both, of course. I have two analog and two digital scopes.

Comment: @jonk, that's exactly why I'm asking. There will come a time when the world no longer has any CRTs and we can't play with vector screens any more. Now this question was closed but I'm fine if word doesn't go out immediately ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that the phosphor CRTs wear out over time. And there are no replacements being made. (I don't think so.) I bought 12 brand new, unused CRTs from the Tektronix Store (very very cheaply) a while back. These are for the 2465B scope I have. So I will have replacement CRTs for a while (depending on if these in storage "keep" well, too -- I expect that not all of them will.)

Comment: A similar device is becoming much rarer, too: the horizontal flyback BJT used in these CRT devices. Used be able to support 200 Hz and better refresh rates for 2k displays. Now I'm pretty sure these are becoming, if not already, unobtanium.

Comment: Oh, and I really like the HP 54645D I have. This scope is digital. But it acts like and works like an analog. It's old (early 1990's I think) for a digital MSO. But it really works like an analog and the newer digitals just didn't pick up on the quality front panel interface and the way the device works, nearly as well as HP did when fielding that device. Perhaps it is because they were competing more with analog at the time. Maybe new manufacturers are dealing the customers who do not have the experience with analog and don't expect or even know about anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think this is a matter of opinion.

As a basic diagnostic tool, either a traditional CRT (Cathode Ray Tube) oscilloscope or a DSO (Digital Sampling Oscilloscope) will give mostly equivalent information.

CRT oscilloscopes are usually bigger, heavier, and thicker due to the physical requirement of the CRT tube itself. There are some hazards associated with a CRT, such as its high voltage drive requirements, the somewhat toxic internal chemicals, and the implosion hazard. These hazards are mitigated as long as the CRT is handled with respect and the oscilloscope cabinet is not opened. I have several but probably wouldn't buy one today.

DSO are usually smaller and more lightweight, since it is basically a small digital computer controlling a high-speed data acquisition system. The display can be a small LCD, and some DSOs don't even have a display: they instead connect to a computer through USB.

There are some things you can do with a DSO that really aren't practical with a CRT: you can capture a deep buffer and trigger on a signal near the end of the buffer, thus "pre-trigger" and see what circumstances preceeded the trigger event. Very useful. The only way to accomplish that with a CRT oscilloscope involve either using a storage CRT (exotic) or an analog delay line (signal integrity issues, space issues).

Both CRT and DSO can "lie" (make incorrect or misleading measurements) under some conditions. I have seen sampling artifacts on an early HP DSO that were not visible with a CRT oscilloscope. But even the CRT oscilloscope's truly analog frontend has bandwidth limitations and loading effects. Early in my career I have had (bad) circuit designs where there was unwanted behaviour such as oscillation, which magically disappeared whenever the scope probe was connected.

Manufacturing (or even maintaining) a CRT today is probably not a great idea. The tubes have limited life span, and very few places still have the capability of manufacturing vacuum tubes. So I don't think you will find any new models of CRT.

For a professional workbench, a decent CRT oscilloscope would be usable if that is what's available, and if the service manual is in hand, and the scope probes are in good shape, and the channels were properly calibrated and compensated. But calibration is going to be a pain. More likely a new lab would use a Selee or some equivalent USB DSO box, since computers are everywhere. A standalone Tek or Keysight DSO would be easier to send for calibration. So unless I can find a pro calibration shop nearby that can support my random CRT scope, it's not suitable for a professional lab.

Comment: Well, I guess you are entitled to your own opinion.

Comment: *So unless I can find a pro calibration shop nearby that can support my random CRT scope, it's not suitable for a professional lab.* As a "general truth" I would disagree with that as I mostly use a scope to see "what's going on" and then it does not matter how well it is calibrated. Your usage might be different of course. Also, if you need regular calibration for an analog scope, you also need it if you use a digital scope.